# haskell equivalent of a typescript map function

Tags: typescript, haskell

I have this [Mapper function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSAnAPAFQMoHsCuSDGEANFGgCIQDOwAlgHZy1Z0B8UAvFABQBmdAXN0q4CEQZhGEAlBzbkqtBkzolheQuOzqIAbQC6M9nIrV6jGs30BuAFA38zalAC2CZIPiIIqOjmcAjb1VgJHoAczZOXgFuOEFfAO9DNmpQujDVSTEoBMCkfSlBVPD9WSgAbxsoKCQIYDw6KDVRADpXMC5Goyg+TqkpWwBfOwc6JwTKDhc3b06yuhbgLAwQ8K4pEh0ARiIAJiIAZhIAFgMWgCssei4AIigbgZHHLAAbCBaXrDDOv0pHoA) in typescript

```
type Mapper<TSource, TDestination> = (fn: (source: TSource) => TDestination, source: TSource[]) => TDestination[];

const mapper: Mapper<number, string> = (fn: (a: number) => string, source: number[]): string[] => {
  return source.map(n => fn(n));
}

const nums = mapper(n => n.toString(), [1,2,3, 4]).join(" ");

console.log(nums);
```

I'm reading about haskell at the moment and wondering how I would do this in haskell.

I have found this type definition in hoogle:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Would I need use `instance` to add concrete types or is there a shorter way?

Comment: It is just `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` if I understand it correctly. Or more generic `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Comment: yes but there are no higher kinded types in typescript, I'm sort of building up to that.  I want to get this right in my head first

Comment: I would I create an instance of the type definition of `map` you gave?  I

Comment: You make something an instance of `Functor`. So `instance Functor Tree` for example.

Comment: I understand that but it that is hard to do in typescript without higher kinded types.  I want to get map working first

Comment: Furthermore you do not need `instance` for concrete types. You can just write for example `map (1+) [1,4,2,5]` and it will return `[2,5,3,6]`

Comment: so where does the map type fit into that.  Just an annotation?

Comment: what would that look like in my example with simply casting a number to a string

Comment: it uses inference to know that you are working with numbers, and it defaults on `Integer`.

Comment: you can use `map show [1,4,2,5]` to convert it to strings. That will return `["1","4","2","5"]`.

Comment: OK but in that example it would look like this:

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map show [1,2,3,4]

Comment: is there a haskell playground like typescripts playground where you can try stuff in the browser?

Comment: you can use the `ghci` shell locally, or use https://tryhaskell.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line is a type alias that gives the name `Mapper` to the type of `map`. In Haskell that'd be:

```
type Mapper a b = (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Then you define a function named `mapper` that's equivalent to `map`. In Haskell that's `mapper = map`, but you can also add the type signature in front:

```
mapper :: Mapper a b
mapper = map
```

Of course the `mapper` function doesn't really serve any purpose here and we could just as well have used `map` directly, but that was already true of the original TypeScript code.

The Haskell equivalent of `n => n.toString()` is `show` and the equivalent of `join` is `intercalate` from `Data.List`, so we get:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

nums = intercalate " " $ mapper show [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And then `console.log` is just `putStrLn`, so:

```
main = putStrLn nums
```

Comment: And this can be shortened with some common functions.  One solution is `unwords . map show`.